# Is there any open source social networking client android app

Tags: java, android, open-source, social-networking

I'm trying to create a social networking client application. Is there any open source social networking application available for me to understand the architecture?

Comment: Probably.  Such requests are off topic here, though.

Comment: Oh! Off topic. I've always fascinated about the social network clients. If it was available it would be a great learning. Was wondering if there is any. A down vote already :(... Guess people think this isn't a useful question. Sorry if it is really unuseful

Comment: It's kinda useful, but SO is more for specific questions regarding actual problems.  General software requests are off topic and turn into lists that are almost inherently subjective (answers will usually mention the poster's favorite software, regardless of its merits, and the whole thing turns into a popularity contest).  I don't agree with the downvote, but eh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks cHao. Will post specific questions here after. 
For the record I was able to find the source of four square. http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/source/checkout Anyone who checks this thread can get benifit of this.